# Dismiss one custom popup UIViewController and present another custom popup UIViewController straight away -SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have an application with a main UIViewController.  When I press a button ("Save") I have a custom popup (UIViewController) present itself.  Within this popup I have another button, whereby if I press it I want to dismiss the current popup view controller and then immediately present another different custom popup view controller.  I am able to dismiss the first popup , but then i get an error(see below).  I am using a protocol to get this working, but I am making a mistake somewhere.  Please can some one advise?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
class mainViewController: UIViewController, popUpDismissedDelegate{

  // CUSTOM PROTOCOL DELEGATE FUNCTION
  func popUpDimissed() {

    // SHOW ANOTHER POPUP TO CREATE CUSTOM HASHTAGS!
    let createTagVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "createTag") as! CreateHashTagPopUpViewController
    present(createTagVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }


 // SAVE PDF
 @IBAction func savePdf(_ sender: Any) {

    // SHOW CUSTOM SELECTION OH HASHTAGS TO ASSIGN PDF
    let popUpVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "hashtagpicker") as! CustomHashTagPopup
    popUpVC.delegate = self
    present(popUpVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }

}



protocol popUpDismissedDelegate {
   func popUpDimissed()
}

class CustomHashTagPopup: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

  var delegate: popUpDismissedDelegate!

 // TAP ON CELLS
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if(indexPath == [0,0]){
        // OPTION TO CREATE A NEW HASHTAG
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.delegate.popUpDimissed()
        }

    }else{
        // DO NOTHING
        // TO SELECT A HASH TAG USE NEEDS TO PRESS ON THE CHECKBOX!
    }
}

}
```

ERROR:

```
 Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously 
 suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're 
 considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height 
 instead.
 popup - viewDidDisappear
 Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x10c1ec1f0) to 
 'zapdocuments.CreateHashTagPopUpViewController' (0x107cd0520).
 2018-08-28 18:18:48.196815+0100 zapdocuments[28989:4660894] Could not 
 cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x10c1ec1f0) to 
 'zapdocuments.CreateHashTagPopUpViewController' (0x107cd0520).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't actually post the error, but I think I know what the problem is. You're probably trying to present the next VC before the old one actually dismissed.

You should use the `completion` parameter of the `dismiss` method and put your delegate callback in there, to ensure you don't try to do anything until it's fully dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

Move your presentation of `createTagVC` to the next loop of the runloop. This should guarantee that the UI is in the correct "non-presenting" state.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    present(createTagVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Sometimes, some things aren't really done until the runloop ends. Best to start fresh in the next one.